# No 'boot from usb' option

Tags: boot, meego

I got a new MeeGo T04 and it is stuck in boot loop.

When I first switched it on it said `Windows error` so I clicked `Repair` and now all it does is boot into an Intel loop.

How can I boot from USB to reinstall OS? There seems to be no option for this- all I can do is enter `BIOS` and there's no option to boot from USB

I've tried hitting <kbd>f1</kbd>-<kbd>f12</kbd> at POST and nothing happens.

The BIOS is from Aptio. I have tried disabling secure boot and fast boot.
The only devices that show in boot are `Windows boot manager` and `Built in EFI shell`.

[image: BIOS screenshot]

[image: BIOS screenshot 2]

Comment: I think you have to plug-in the usb drive first to get usb boot option .

Comment: fixed it now, had to have the usb in GPT partition. thanks anyway

Comment: Then, answer it yourself, please